# Angular multipart upload with .NET Core, file becomes null in the back-end

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I am trying to upload a simple file to my backend dotnet core application but the file comes as `null` but `description` is not null.

.NET Core controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImageUpload(IFormFile file, [FromQuery] string description)
{
    if (file == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Failed to upload file");
    }

    // File is alway null!

    return Ok("Good!");
}
```

Angular file:

```
async upload(file: File, description: string = '') {
  if (file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    return await this.http.post(route('image', 'upload'), formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      params: { description },
      responseType: "text"
    }).toPromise();
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to post data as **FormData()** from angular you can also set **description** using **.append()** to **fd** object in service method. you will get all appended data in API using Request => **Request.Form**

**API**

```
 [HttpPost("SaveProfilePic")]
public ResponseResult SaveProfilePic(IFormFile files)
{
 var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
 var form = Request.Form;
}
```

**Angular**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="Save(f)" #f="ngForm">
<input type="file" name="profile_pic" (change)="setProfilePic($event)">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
Save(form)
{
 this.MyService.SaveProfilePic(this.profile_pic, 'description').subscribe(res => {

 })
}
    setProfilePic(event:any)
    {
     if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
     this.profile_pic = event.target.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
     reader.onload = (event:any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
     }

     }
    }
```

**MyService**

```
public SaveProfilePic(picture: File,fileName): any {
 const fd = new FormData();
 fd.append('image', picture, fileName);
 return this._http.post(this.url + 'MyController/SaveProfilePic', fd);
}
```